# Why this java recursive function is not working properly?

Tags: java, function, recursion

```
public class cash
{
    public void test(int a)
    {
        if(a<5)
        {
            System.out.print(a+" ");
            test(++a);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        System.out.println("fin");
    }
    public static void main(String[] argsc)
    {
        cash c=new cash();       
        c.test(1);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
1 2 3 4 fin
5
fin
4
fin
3
fin
2
fin
```

why ? I think the output should be 1 2 3 4 fin.
thank you very much.

Comment: Please improve the post quality using the <code> tag

Comment: There is no ending clause for recursion. and the fin is always executed.

Comment: @jurka: There is ending clause: `a>=5`. The recursion is invoked only if `a<5`, thus `!(a<5) == a>=5` terminates it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so this is your recursive method:

```
public void test(int a)
{
    if(a<5)
    {
        System.out.print(a+" ");
        test(++a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    System.out.println("fin");
}
```

every statement in this method gets invoked when you call it. lets think about the semantics in this method.
This list describes in words, what your method does:

- check if a<5. if true

  - print out a.
  - call `test(++a)`,
  - print out the incremented a
- print out `"fin"`

Your first problem is, that you always (during every invocation of `test()`) print out `"fin"`. put it in an `else {...}` block to fix it.

Your second problem is, that you print out the incremented value of a, thats why you get your output. remove the second println-statement (`System.out.println(a);`) to fix that.

The correct implementation of your method would look like this:

```
public void test(int a)
{
    if(a<5) {
        System.out.print(a);
        test(++a);
    } else {
        System.out.println("fin");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class cash
{
    public void test(int a)
    {
        if(a<5)
        {
            System.out.print(a+" ");
            test(++a);
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("fin");
    }
    public static void main(String[] argsc)
    {
        cash c=new cash();       
        c.test(1);
    }
}
```

Note: above code has not been tested.

**EDIT**

Your code didn't have a stop condition after it reached `a=5`; therefore, the System.out.print line after calling itself recursively was always going to execute as the stack was being popped; hence the output:

```
1
2
3
4 -- function stops calling itself here and returns. Stack is popped
fin -- Program continues executing the line from the last recursive call (prints fin)
5 --  As above, there were 2 lines pending to execute from the previous call, the system.out.println after test(a++) 
fin  -- And the system.out.println('fin');
4  -- Stack is popped, same 2 lines as above. prints 4 since the value of a when the function was called was 4 then continues on to the next line, which prints 'fin' 
fin
... and so on
```

Comment: thank you ,I just wonder why strange output occurred, whats wrong with that or recursive function works like that? thanks

Comment: I would normally write the stop condition first, but this is the simplest change.

Comment: @NamoBhagavan I just ran a test in C# and I see that my modification worked. Now that I am sure it works, I'll explain why your code didn't work on my answer.

Comment: @NamoBhagavan posted my edit explaining why your recursive function was wrong. I hope my explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code will execute:

```
test(1); // Outputs "1", calls test(2), outputs "2" and "fin" after that
test(2); // Outputs "2", calls test(3), outputs "3" and "fin" after that
test(3); // Outputs "3", calls test(4), outputs "4" and "fin" after that
test(4); // Outputs "4", calls test(5), outputs "5" and "fin" after that
test(5); // Outputs "fin" after that
```

Basically:

```
"1 " + test(2) + "2" + "fin"
"1" + ("2" + test(3) + "3" + "fin") + "2" + "fin"
"1" + ("2" + ("3" + test(4) + "4" + "fin") + "3" + "fin") + "2" + "fin"
"1" + ("2" + ("3" + ("4" + test(5) + "5" + "fin") + "4" + "fin") + "3" + "fin") + "2" + "fin"
"1" + ("2" + ("3" + ("4" + ("fin") + "5" + "fin") + "4" + "fin") + "3" + "fin") + "2" + "fin"
```

So your output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

NO!. The o/p is correct...`test(++a)` will keep calling itself again and again till a=5...once this gets complete, only after that it will print the next line for other values..

test(5)->test(4)->test(3)->test(2)->test(1)

Recursive functions uses `stack`...so the last in will be first out...

hv a look [here](http://www.toves.org/books/java/ch17-recur/index.html).....

Answer (score 0):

This is where using a debugger would be useful.  You would be able to see that as it unwinds the recursion, fin is out put every time, not just when you decide to stop.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do in the recursion is print the element, and then recursively call the function.

Let's have a look on the call stack of the recursion. [we will denote each recursive call by its argument `a`]

At first, you only invoke the method with one element

```
| |
|1|
---
```

you will print "1" and invoke recursive call with 2, now the top will be:

```
|2|
|1|
---
```

You enter the method again and print the element, `2`, and reinvoke with 3, and get:

```
|3|
|2|
|1|
---
```

continue this logic, and you will end up printing 1,2,3,4, and get the stack trace:

```
|5|
|4|
|3|
|2|
|1|
---
```

Now, the condition does not meet, so you only print fin, and return - results in popping the first element:

```
|4|
|3|
|2|
|1|
---
```

when you are back from the recursive call, you print the top+1 [`5`] and then `fin`, and again, pop the element from the head of the stack trace, and get:

```
|3|
|2|
|1|
---
```

Now again, you print the head+1: `4` and `fin`, and pop one more element....

Continue this logic until the stack is empty, and you get exactly what the program printed!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code... You will understand How this program is running

```
public class cash
{
    public void test(int a)
    {
    if(a<5)
    {
        System.out.print(a+" ");
        System.out.print("test 1 - " + a);
        test(++a);
        System.out.print("test 2 - " + a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    System.out.println("fin");
    }
    public static void main(String[] argsc)
    {
    cash c=new cash();       
    c.test(1);
    }
}
```

### Update 1

To get what you want, use Below

```
public class cash
{
    public void test(int a)
    {
    if(a<5)
    {
        System.out.print(a+" ");
//            System.out.print("test 1 - " + a);
        test(++a);
        if (a==5)
        System.exit(0);
//            System.out.print("test 2 - " + a);
        System.out.println(a);
    } else {
    System.out.println("fin");
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] argsc)
    {
    cash c=new cash();       
    c.test(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

During the fourth recursive invocation of your test method the a variable is incremented to 5 before you invoke the method (test(++a)). Since a < 5 is false it will proceed in printing fin and returning (hence your output: 1 2 3 4 fin)

Soon after returns however, it will continue executing the rest of the code which will print 5 followed by fin. The same thing goes on and on for any previous recursive iteration in your code, hence the recursive output: X fin (where X is the value of a in each preceding iteration)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your solution is that the exit condition of the recursion (`a` being greater than or equal to `5`) is getting executed *always*. It should be executed only *once*, the first time the condition holds true - so you must put it in an `else` block. Also, it's a bad idea assigning to a parameter (the `++a` part).

The simplest way I can think of for writing the `test` method is:

```
public void test(int a) {
    if (a < 5) {
        System.out.print(a + " ");
        test(a + 1);
    } else {
        System.out.println("fin");
    }
}
```